# Switch between portrait & landscape orientation without restarting activity

Tags: android, screen-orientation

Is their any way to switch from portrait to landscape orientation & vice versa without restarting activity.. If i stop restarting of activity by adding android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize", I am not being able to switch, but what i need is not to restart activity anyway. Any solution please.

Comment: No. Please just take your time to learn how to use the mechanisms provided by the Android platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override [`onConfigurationChanged(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) method in your Activity and do there whatever you want with the UI, for example, call `setContentView(resID)`.

Comment: I have a question, I did as u recommended & get the result when i tilt my cell i get a new layout & vice versa but the layout which  appears after tilting is not reading the activity e.g button onclick listener not working why ??..

Comment: That's because you've subscribed for clicks at `onCreate` for buttons from other layout instance. When switching the layout, you need to re-subscribe for any events. **And be extremely careful with references to unused instances, since memory leaks in your case are highly probable.**

Comment: my new layout is of same name inside layout-land..

Comment: The name is the same, but the **instances** are different.

Comment: This is so frustrating, by default killing an activity while rotation.. can u give me a little described solution.. em stuck due to this

Comment: Destroying/creating Activity while rotating the device is actually very useful - you don't need to manage many things manually (as you've probably noticed). So, if the only reason why you're looking for the solution to override the default behavior is that it's frustrating, then it's not the best way :) Overriding would be even more frustrating.

Comment: :) Yeah its another side of the picture..